# need help detecting game lighting in my lua script

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make a script, in Lua code, that detects the level of lighting in my game. I am pretty new to Lua so as far as I know lighting in the game is a number (2, 10, 5).

```
if game:GetService("Lighting").Brightness < 1 then 
    game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.output.Text = "You are getting cold";
end
```

I am not sure if it is just not detecting `game:GetService("lighting").Brightness` as a number or if the game does not know what `game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.output.Text` is. I've testing this multiple times, making small alteration every time, but most of the time I got no error. With the code now there is no error message.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use game.***StarterGui***.
StarterGui is what gui is put inside a player's PlayerGui when they join. Players do NOT see StarterGui.
Instead:

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    if game:GetService("Lighting").Brightness < 1 then 
       plr.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.output.Text = "You are getting cold";
    end
end)
```

(player).PlayerGui is the gui the player sees. StarterGui will not auto update or modify the game's players' guis when it is changed.
If you have any more questions feel free to ask them with a comment! ^-^

Roblox lua documentation:
https://www.developer.roblox.com/en-us

Comment: Your link is not working, try this instead: https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/. Also, great answer!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will try this out right away.

Comment: The new script didn't work. I am using a textbox with a name of ```output```. Can I use textboxes for something like this?

Comment: Can you show me the error Roblox Studio is giving you?